# data.table rowwise product

Tags: r, data.table, data-wrangling

Given the following DT:

```
DT <- data.table(
  Year = c(1, 2, 3), 
  factor = c(0.9, 0.8, 0.7)
)
```

I would like to get this additional colum "factorcumulative ":

```
DT2 <- data.table(
  Year = c(1, 2, 3), 
  factor = c(0.9, 0.8, 0.7),
  factorcumulative = c(0.9, (0.8*0.9), (0.8*0.9*0.7))
)
```

any suggestion for a compact and elegant way?

Comment: Maybe you want the `cumprod` function.

Comment: How would it work in this case @benson23?

Comment: got it ```DT <- data.table(
  Year = c(1, 2, 3), 
  factor = c(0.9, 0.8, 0.7)
)
DT <- DT[, test := cumprod(factor)]```

Comment: If you'va solved the problem yourself, you can create an answer and accept it.